# F# Agent.PostAndReply vs Agent.PostAndAsyncReply

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I wrote the following two functions:

```
let requestAsync qry = dispatcher.PostAndAsyncReply (fun chan -> Query (qry chan))
let request qry = qry |> requestAsync |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Now I was wondering if I would have any incentive to writing request like this instead:

```
let request qry = dispatcher.PostAndReply (fun chan -> Query(qry chan))
```

I wasn't able to decompile the two implementations and as such, I don't know if the second one might be more efficient or whatnot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is at

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs

though not exactly perspicuous... I don't think there's much difference; I would call `PostAndReply`, but they're both doing roughly the same thing and I would not expect a significant difference.  (As always, if you care deeply, then measure for your exact scenario.)